# how to check already scraped URL in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am giving my python script a list of links through a text file to scrape in BeautifulSoup.It then generates a output HTML file of that url and saves it in directory.

I want to check if a url is already scraped OR if url HTML file already exists.
I want a solution that if url is already scraped and its HTML file is saved than program should skip to next url that is not scraped.

I tried to solve problem by parsing url's path and comparing with it's HTML file's name in directory.

```
import os.path
from urllib.parse import urlparse


def validate(urls):
    for link in urls:
        parse = urlparse(link)
        files = parse.path + '.html' # make HTML file 
                for names in files.split():
                      if not os.path.isfile(names): 
                            URLS='somewebsite.com/'+link.replace('.html','') 
     return URLS
```

I want to eliminate comparing urls with files, instead using another approach to check urls which are not scraped.

Comment: It's "scrape," not "scrap."  "Scrap" is what you do to an old car when it no longer runs.

Comment: How else will you keep track of URLs you've scraped? You could append the URLs to a csv file, or a list then pickle the list at the end of your script. But you're going to have to save the URLs you've scraped already somewhere if you will run the program multiple times.

Comment: @MasonCaiby thanks buddy....I'll try that approach